# How to allow C libraries to use caller's logging?

Tags: c, logging

This [style-guide](https://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/kay/libabc.git;a=blob_plain;f=README) for Linux libraries suggests "Allow the app to hook the libs logging into its logging facility."  By what mechanism is this typically done? A function that takes a pointer to a logging function?  Can you show examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example from SQLite. You can set up how it logs by calling [`sqlite3_config()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/config.html) with a [`CONFIG_LOG`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_config_getmalloc.html#sqliteconfiglog) argument. You pass in a function pointer, and a void pointer. The function pointer takes three arguments; a void pointer, an integer, and a `char *`. When SQLite needs to log something, it calls your function pointer, passing in the void pointer that you passed to `CONFIG_LOG`, a result code, and a string containing the log message.

> SQLITE_CONFIG_LOG
>
> The SQLITE_CONFIG_LOG option takes two arguments: a pointer to a function with a call signature of `void(*)(void*,int,const char*)`, and a pointer to void. If the function pointer is not NULL, it is invoked by sqlite3_log() to process each logging event. If the function pointer is NULL, the sqlite3_log() interface becomes a no-op. The void pointer that is the second argument to SQLITE_CONFIG_LOG is passed through as the first parameter to the application-defined logger function whenever that function is invoked. The second parameter to the logger function is a copy of the first parameter to the corresponding sqlite3_log() call and is intended to be a result code or an extended result code. The third parameter passed to the logger is log message after formatting via sqlite3_snprintf(). The SQLite logging interface is not reentrant; the logger function supplied by the application must not invoke any SQLite interface. In a multi-threaded application, the application-defined logger function must be threadsafe.

You can see the actual implementation of `sqlite3_log()` in [SQLite's `printf.c`](http://www.sqlite.org/src/artifact/4a9f882f1c1787a8b494a2987765acf9d97ac21f). It uses `snprintf()` (their wrapper around it, that is) to print into a buffer on the stack, since logging functions may be called when you can't call `malloc`, and then pass the result back into the function pointer the user has configured, along with the value they provided and the error code.

```
/*
** This is the routine that actually formats the sqlite3_log() message.
** We house it in a separate routine from sqlite3_log() to avoid using
** stack space on small-stack systems when logging is disabled.
**
** sqlite3_log() must render into a static buffer.  It cannot dynamically
** allocate memory because it might be called while the memory allocator
** mutex is held.
*/
static void renderLogMsg(int iErrCode, const char *zFormat, va_list ap){
  StrAccum acc;                          /* String accumulator */
  char zMsg[SQLITE_PRINT_BUF_SIZE*3];    /* Complete log message */

  sqlite3StrAccumInit(&acc, zMsg, sizeof(zMsg), 0);
  acc.useMalloc = 0;
  sqlite3VXPrintf(&acc, 0, zFormat, ap);
  sqlite3GlobalConfig.xLog(sqlite3GlobalConfig.pLogArg, iErrCode,
                           sqlite3StrAccumFinish(&acc));
}

/*
** Format and write a message to the log if logging is enabled.
*/
void sqlite3_log(int iErrCode, const char *zFormat, ...){
  va_list ap;                             /* Vararg list */
  if( sqlite3GlobalConfig.xLog ){
    va_start(ap, zFormat);
    renderLogMsg(iErrCode, zFormat, ap);
    va_end(ap);
  }
}
```

Or you could take a look at [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html#section-5.1). By default, it logs errors to stderr, but you can provide your own callback to override that. You call `png_set_error_fn()`, passing your `png_struct`, a void pointer, and two callbacks, one for errors and one for warnings. It will then call your function pointers with two arguments; the `png_struct`, via which you can access your void pointer with `png_get_error_ptr()`, and a `char *`. Again, libpng handles the `snprintf()`, and just passes a single `char *` to the logging callback.

Answer (score 0):

For example, in the configuration for your library, you could have a user-defined function pointer:

```
struct my_lib_config
{
    void (* log) (const char * message);
};
```

With a sensible default:

```
void log_default (const char * message)
{
    fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", message);
}

if (!config.log)
    config.log = log_default;
```

With this your library would log to stderr by default, unless the application sets the `log` function pointer to their own function.

Comment: Seems like with that function signature I'd be doing a lot of snprintf'ing into static buffers on my stack...

Comment: Well, feel free to make it printf-style. I was just trying to keep the example simple.

Comment: Yeah, less interested in simplicity, I was more interested in how it was typically done.